# Where can I find more information on creating a driver for a usb device in C / linux?

Tags: c, linux, usb, driver, device-driver

I know how about the capture part in wireshark. Parsing and figuring out the data shouldn't be a problem. Links to where I can get more information, tutorials or forums on how to target and receive from the device, or related content would be most helpful.

Comment: There are often some pointers in the kernel sources (the included docs, mind, no point reading the actuall source unless you have to...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any shortage of information on the subject.  **[Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+usb+device+driver)**

---

[Chapter 13: USB Drivers](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch13.pdf) (pdf link) of [*Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition*](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)  might be a good place to start.